# jQuery.getJSON not being called?

Tags: php, jquery, json

This is my code:

```
$.getJSON('/test.php', {q: value},  function(data, status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('error: ' + status);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log('ok');
    }
});
```

The test.php looks like this:

```
echo 'foobar';
```

I am not getting any error messages but it also seems that the request is not made. Any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your php file is not outputting JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're sending back (`foobar`) isn't valid JSON, so you're triggering the error handler. But since you haven't listened for errors, you're not seeing anything. The callback you give `getJSON` is the `success` callback (see [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)).

Here's one way you'd handle both success and error:

```
$.getJSON('/test.php', {q: value})
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log('ok');
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
        console.log('error: ', error);
    });
```

Here's how you'd send back a valid JSON response:

```
echo json_encode('foobar');
```

That outputs the valid JSON

```
"foobar"
```

(It used to be that the top level of JSON text had to be an object or an array, but that hasn't been true for years, so just a string is fine.)